# \SIlist with uncertainty AND units

Tags: siunitx

Using the `siunitx` package, I want to create lists of values that have both uncertainties and units. They should appear in the document like this example:

4 ± 2 %, 3 ± 2 %, 2 ± 1 % and 3 ± 2%

Here is how I was hoping to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single,list-units=repeat]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

  % a single value with unit and uncertainty
  \SI{84.10 \pm 6.99}{\percent}

  % a list of values with units and uncertainties
  \SIlist{4 \pm 2; 3 \pm 2; 2 \pm 1; 3 \pm 2}{\percent}

\end{document}
```

The single value turns out fine:

> 84.10 ± 6.99 %

However, contrary to my expectations, the list looks like this:

> (4 ± 2) %, (3 ± 2) %, (2 ± 1) % and (3 ± 2) %

It seems that the option `multi-part-units=single` has no effect inside the list, and instead the default `multi-part-units=brackets` is applied.

I wasn't able find any hints on that in the documentation or elsewhere, and would be grateful, if someone could indicate were my error lies.

Comment: Please note that the way siunitx works is, strictly speaking, the correct one, as (4 ± 2) % means the same as 4 % ± 2 %, but 4 ± 2 % strictly speaking means as much as (400 ± 2) %.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of the parenthesis by issuing

```
\SIlist[open-bracket={},close-bracket={}]{4 \pm 2; 3 \pm 2; 2 \pm 1; 3 \pm 2}{\percent}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single,list-units=repeat]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

  % a single value with unit and uncertainty
  \SI{84.10 \pm 6.99}{\percent}

  % a list of values with units and uncertainties
  \SIlist[open-bracket={},close-bracket={}]{4 \pm 2; 3 \pm 2; 2 \pm 1; 3 \pm 2}{\percent}

\end{document}
```

[image]